# Find Object Array and its Properties from Ajax Post Request

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, object

I'm sending an AJAX request to an internal PHP and receiving back an object. The object has properties of "data" and "status", yet when I try to access them, it does not return anything. How can I show each property separately?

For reference, the returned obj array is:

```
{"data:[{"tagId":"8787","tagDescription":"001","tagMin":"0","tagMax":"100"},{"tagId":"8729","tagDescription":"1","tagMin":"44","tagMax":"555"}]
```

```
function GetAll() {
  var PostRequest ={};
  PostRequest['tagId']= 'all';

  $.post('php here',PostRequest,ShowAllTags);
}


function ShowAllTags( responseData, responseStatus ) { 
  console.log(responseStatus);

  var tagData = {};
  tagData = responseData;
  console.log(tagData['data']);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is your data an object or a JSON string? The data snippet you've included is malformed and somewhat ambiguous. Please `console.log(responseData)` and copy+paste it into your question exactly as it appears.

Comment: {"data":[{"tagId":"8787","tagDescription":"001","tagMin":"0","tagMax":"100"},{"tagId":"77","tagDescription":"FALSE","tagMin":"36","tagMax":"176"},{"tagId":"78","tagDescription":"FLAG","tagMin":"-2","tagMax":"85"}]status":"Action:GetAll : 265 Tags returned"}

Comment: it returns 256 of these tags

Comment: i thing problem with response data, giving in problem. missing parentheses `}` and missing double quote `"` on data object. Update your question, so that helpful in the future. And what is the problem your are facing is not clear, make the problem clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to the above comment mention by me, The problem is with json object, in response.
So first of all fix that,

Generic solution of this problem will be;

```
var obj = [{"tagId":"8787","tagDescription":"001","tagMin":"0","tagMax":"100"},{"tagId":"8729","tagDescription":"1","tagMin":"44","tagMax":"555"}];



 obj.forEach(function(value, index){console.log(value.tagId)});
```

This might help, how to get value of each property